# Resolving kubernetes endpoints hostname to a given cluster, from within

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I have a Kubernetes cluster on AWS (no EKS) with each service having endpoint urls to which they communicate "hardcoded" within their docker image.

Now I want to create at the same aws account a clone of that cluster, keeping the first one intact. The problem is that when I create a service, its ingress entry overwrites in route53 the one used for the original cluster.

What I would like to achieve?

- For every hostname defined within a cluster I want to have it resolved internally to point to that cluster entity, as long as it exists there.
- I want to have hostnames registered in route53 only for the original cluster, the second one not affecting those entries in any way. So to speak I want to have an explicit option to register it or not in route53.

I use [external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns) and [nginx ingress controller](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx).

Comment: For your first requirement, Kubernetes DNS does that for you: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/. You should be able to nicely and idiomatically have pods address other services purely by service names rather than a FQDN, those service names should be the addresses you hardcore (if any).

Comment: (Hit send too soon...) For the second requirement, simply don’t deploy `external-dns` to the second cluster. And for good hygiene, don’t include the external DNS annotations on the services in your second cluster. If you do this, the second cluster is not an exact copy of the first, but it sounds like you don’t really want a *truly* exact copy.